# parsing wordpress into IOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, json, wordpress, swift

I have **UIImage View (post image), label(post title), UIWebView(post content)**,
and I have this code to parse wordpress JSON posts to my app

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    var maindata = (data[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary)

      theTitle =  (maindata["post_title"] as? String)!
    theImg =  (maindata["image"] as? String)!
    theDate =  (maindata["post_date_gmt"] as? String)!
    theBody = (maindata["post_content"] as? String)!
}
```

and I have installed JSON Api plugin on my wordpress,

but I don't know how to parse to my app ??

this is my whole code

```
import UIKit
import Haneke


var theTitle = ""
var theImg = ""
var theDate = ""
var theBody = ""


class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var myTable: UITableView!

    // to refresh with pull down

    var ref:UIRefreshControl?

    // to refresh with pull down




    var data = []


    var prog:MBProgressHUD!




    override func viewDidLoad()

    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // to refresh with pull down
        self.ref = UIRefreshControl()
        self.ref?.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "اسحب للأسفل للتحديث")
        self.ref?.addTarget(self, action: "ref:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        // to refresh with pull down

        myTable.addSubview(self.ref!)








        var heloWorldTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.0001, target: self, selector: Selector("sayHello"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

        myTable.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        myTable.dataSource = self
        myTable.delegate = self





    }
// to refresh with pull down
    func ref (sender:UIRefreshControl)
    {
        self.myTable.reloadData()
        self.ref?.endRefreshing()
    }
    // to refresh with pull down



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.


        func dataJsonFromURL(url:String)->NSArray
        {

            if var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url)!) {

            return (NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as! NSArray)
        }
            else {
                return data

        }


        }
    }


    func dataJsonFromURL(url:String)->NSArray
    {
        var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url)!)
        return (NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: nil) as! NSArray)
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        if data.count == 0 {
            prog = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)

            prog.labelText = "جاري تحميل البيانات"
            prog.detailsLabelText = "الرجاء الإنتظار"
            return 0
        }
        else
        { MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)
            return data.count
        }
    }



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = myTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!
        newsCell


        var maindata = (data[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary)

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None


        cell.titleNews!.text = maindata["post_title"] as? String
        cell.dateNews!.text = maindata["post_date_gmt"] as? String

       if var urlImg = NSURL(string: (maindata["image"] as? String)!)
        {
          cell.imgNews.hnk_setImageFromURL(urlImg, placeholder: nil, format:nil, failure:nil, success:nil)

       }


        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        return cell

    }


    @IBAction func rfreshB(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        prog = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(view, animated: true)

                prog.labelText = "جاري تحميل البيانات"
                prog.detailsLabelText = "الرجاء الإنتظار"
        //data = dataJsonFromURL("http://hhz20.co/newstest/PhpFile/admin/show.php")
        data = dataJsonFromURL("http://hhz20.co/testing/PhpFile/admin/show.php")
        myTable.reloadData()
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


        var maindata = (data[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary)

          theTitle =  (maindata["post_title"] as? String)!
        theImg =  (maindata["image"] as? String)!
        theDate =  (maindata["post_date_gmt"] as? String)!
        theBody = (maindata["post_content"] as? String)!
    }

    func sayHello ()
    {
        data = dataJsonFromURL("http://hhz20.co/testing/PhpFile/admin/show.php")
        myTable.reloadData()


    }



}
```

Comment: You mean you don't know how to make an URL request to get the data from your webpage to the app? Or how to convert the URL response (JSON text) to `NSDictionary`?

Comment: I need a help with coding please

Comment: What type is `data` in this : `(data[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary)`?

Comment: I HAVE POSTED ALL OF MY CODE